# outdoor heater wiring wire and circuit breaker

Tags: outdoor, heater

I am installing an outdoor heater that is 3000 watt, 12.5 amp, 240 v.  What size breaker and wire
should be used?

Comment: Is it labeled 12.5 amps, or are you just assuming that from 3000W?  **What do the instructions say to use?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just answer your question, You will need #12 AWG wire which is good for 20 Amps and a 20 Amp breaker.
If you add more information about the location and the heater, we might be able to help out with the installation.